# Distinct List of Lists With Set

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I created a list of lists and then tried to get a distinct list of the lists using set(), but it appears as though i cant use list on a set.

Is there another way to accomplish this with a concise statement that performs well?

**CODE**

```
x = [1,2]
y = [1,2]
z = [2,3]

xyz = []

xyz.append(x)
xyz.append(y)
xyz.append(z)

set(xyz)
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**Goal**

```
xyz = [[1,2],[2,3]]
```

Comment: If you use `tuple`s rather than `list`s for the inner containers, your code will work. Since `tuple`s are immutable, they can be `hash`ed.

Comment: Nice, i think that will work for what im doing, thank you!  If i need to keep it as a list in the future, is there another way i can do it while keeping the list?

Comment: Not unless you want some quadratic loops

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that sounds scary. I'll stick with a tuple :)

Comment: @Blckknght hey, if you want to post your solution as an answer ill mark it as accepted because you answered first. Otherwise i'll accept Joel's. Let me know what you prefer

Comment: You still have the lists as x, y, and z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list members are hashable, it will work

```
x = [1,2]
y = [1,2]
z = [2,3]
xyz = []

xyz.append(tuple(x))
xyz.append(tuple(y))
xyz.append(tuple(z))

print xyz
xyz_set = set(xyz)
print xyz_set
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want to preserve order and keep your lists, you could use  generator function to remove the dupes from your list:

```
xyz = [x, y, z]

def remove_dupe_subs(l):
    seen = set()
    for sub in l:
        tup = tuple(sub)
        if tup not in seen:
            yield sub
            seen.add(tup)

xyz[:] = remove_dupe_subs(xyz)
```

Or using a generator expression taking advantage of the fact `set.add` returns None :

```
seen = set()
xyz[:] = (seen.add(tup) or sub for sub, tup in zip(xyz, map(tuple, xyz)) if tup not in seen)
print(xyz)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit convoluted, but this will do the trick in a single line:

```
xyz=[list(x) for x in list(set((tuple(x),tuple(y),tuple(z))))]
```